# What kind of product is on the market for flooring transitions with large height differences?

Tags: flooring, floor, transition

The bathroom floor of my house is more than 2 inches higher than the hallway floor to which it is adjoined.

A normal transition piece will **not** work.

How could I make something in the shape of a triangulair wedge-shape ramp?

Ideally, a wheel chair could smoothly travel from the hallway to the bathroom without there being a stair-step.

Comment: This is normally done with some dense wood such as oak or ash and a tablesaw.

Answer (score 5):

Three options come to mind. If you have basic wood working tools, make a ramp out of a sheet of plywood. You could also construct a ramp form and pour some mortar into it. Or get a 2" x 12" piece of wood and bring it to a wood working class or cabinet maker and have them cut, plane a diagonal corner to corner line.

If you don't feel like constructing anything, there are many threshold ramps on the internet. Below is one from Wayfair.

[image]

Comment: Except this is a ramp into a hallway, so it needs to taper in *three* directions.